# How to use gradle dependancy hosted on a private github repo protected by 2 Two-factor authentication?

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Our company code hosted on a private github repos and our cradentials use Two-factor authentication. so I need username and password  plus "Authenticator" mobile app.

I created an Android liberary and hosted it inside our company repos because it should not be accessed externally.

our apps should depend on liberary like this :

```
repositories {
    maven {

        url "https://github.com/xyz/myliberary/raw/master/releases"
        credentials
                {
                    username "${username}"
                    password "${password}"
                }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.xyz.maven:myliberary:1.0.0'
}
```

This failed to work. When I hosted my liberary on a public repo, it worked. so I think the issue is in using Two-factor authentication. An help ?